# Get the set of a grouped aggregated list

Tags: python, group-by, set

How do I get the [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) of the following `groupby`?

```
grouped = df.groupby('optionType').strike.agg(list)
```

if grouped looks like this:

```
for key in grouped.keys():
    print(key,  grouped[key])

C [2640, 2635, 2630, 2625, 2625]
P [2460, 2455, 2455, 2425, 2425, 2420]
```

After I want it to look like this:

```
C [2640, 2635, 2630, 2625]
P [2460, 2455, 2425, 2420]
```

In other words, no duplicates in the grouped elements.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you give an example and the output you're looking for?

Comment: See Original Post

Comment: Then you should just do `df.groupby('optionType').strike.agg(set)`, or if you want a list: `df.groupby('optionType').strike.agg(lambda x: list(set(x)))`

Comment: I must be getting tired. Thanks.